# Задачи в Maple

Tags: maple

Подскажите,пожалуйста,как написать код такой задачи:
 дана система дифуров х'=f1(х,у),y'=f2(х,у)

1. Найти точки покоя системы.
2. Кажд. из точек исследовать на устойчивость.
3. Вывести название особой точки
4. Построить фазовый портрет.

Если кто делал уже, помогите.

Comment: maple? я разве я один кто первый раз про это слышу? я погуглил - это типа автокада =) на проффорумах надо смотреть такие ответы...

Comment: @Gorets, из нас троих вы, видимо, один. Насчет автокада не знаю, но небольшая схожесть с Матлабом у него тоже есть, правда инструментарий и возможности шире в области символьных вычислений. К сожалению, не помню совершенно ничего.

Comment: Можете какие-нибудь проффорумы на эту тему подсказать?